# CakePHP: How to allow a RESTful view action (get) to accept two params?

Tags: php, rest, cakephp

After applied auto RESTful routes using `$routes->resources('ProcessoJudicial')`

I would like to allow my view method to accept two or more parameters (by domains rules), something like:

```
public function view(string $cnj, string $sigla_tribunal = null) {
        ...
}
```

Works well using this URI:

http://localhost/myapp/processo_judicial/22/

But when I try two params like:

http://localhost/myapp/processo_judicial/22/11/

I got an error:

```
Error: Your routing resulted in Processo_judicial as a controller name. 
Ensure that your URL /processo_judicial/22/11/ is using the same inflection style as your routes do. By default applications use DashedRoute and URLs should use - to separate multi-word controller names.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource routes have a fixed URL format that doesn't accept trailing arguments, you can't append values to them:

| HTTP format | URL.format | Controller action invoked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GET | /recipes.format | RecipesController::index() |
| GET | /recipes/123.format | RecipesController::view(123) |
| POST | /recipes.format | RecipesController::add() |
| PUT | /recipes/123.format | RecipesController::edit(123) |
| PATCH | /recipes/123.format | RecipesController::edit(123) |
| DELETE | /recipes/123.format | RecipesController::delete(123) |

**[Cookbook > Routing > RESTful Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#restful-routing)**

There's some configuration that can be applied to change things up, namely the `connectOptions` option (which basically ends up as the 3rd argument of `RouteBuilder::connect()`) that allows to for example define passed parameters, and the `map` option under which custom paths for actions can be defined.

Here's an example that would override the built-in `view` route config, and define an additional route element to be passed:

```php
$routes->resources('ModelName', [
    'connectOptions' => [
        'acronym' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
        'pass' => ['id', 'acronym'],
    ],
    'map' => [
        'view' => [
            'action' => 'view',
            'method' => 'GET',
            'path' => '{id}/{acronym}',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

If that is an outlier, then it's probably fine to do it this way. If you however have to do that for many more routes, then you should consider ditching the `resources()` shorthand, and instead create all the required routes on your own.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > RESTful Routing > Custom Route Classes for Resource Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes-for-resource-routes)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > RESTful Routing > Mapping Additional Resource Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#mapping-additional-resource-routes)**

Comment: needs a comma after => 'view' (tried to edit but I was not able)